# Unique "key" prop in React when returning list with multiple children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to render multiple lists in a react component. I create my lists in the following manner:

```
var jobResources = null;
if (this.state.jobResources) {
  jobResources = _.map(this.state.jobResources, function(jobResource, i) {
    return <ul><li key={i}>{jobResource.resource.name}</li><li key={Math.floor(Math.random()  * (1000 - 100)) + 100}>{translations.resourceType[jobResource.resource.resourceType.name]}</li></ul>
  })
}
```

When it comes to rendering, I render the list thus:

```
  <div>
  <h2>Who is Working on the Project?</h2>
  {this.state.jobResources ? jobResources : null}
  </div>
```

The resulting render is as follows:

```
<ul data-reactid=".0.2.0.2.1:0">
  <li data-reactid=".0.2.0.2.1:0.$0">Mark Smith</li>
  <li data-reactid=".0.2.0.2.1:0.$270">Hair &amp; MakeUp</li>
</ul>
<ul data-reactid=".0.2.0.2.1:1">
  <li data-reactid=".0.2.0.2.1:1.$1">John Doe</li>
  <li data-reactid=".0.2.0.2.1:1.$377">Photographer</li>
</ul>
```

As far as I see it, the keys are unique. However, react gives me the following warning:

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key"
>   prop. Check the render method of `JobDetailPage`. See
>   http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children
>   for more information.

Could anyone tell me what is the mistake that I am making and what would be the correct way of going about this?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This utility function from lodash/underscore solves it easily:

```
key={_.uniqueId()}
```

Comment: Wow, that's definitely simpler. Thanks!

Comment: Generating random `key` is a bed practice. It forces the `<li>` elements to be re-rendered even when the `<li>` contents didn't change. More details here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1342#issuecomment-39230939

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, figured it out. Apparently, the list element should have a key as well. The correct way of creating the list therefore would be:

```
var jobResources = null;
if (this.state.jobResources) {
  jobResources = _.map(this.state.jobResources, function(jobResource) {
    return <ul key={jobResource.id}><li key={jobResource.resource.name}>{jobResource.resource.name}</li><li key={jobResource.resource.resourceType.name}>{translations.resourceType[jobResource.resource.resourceType.name]}</li></ul>
  })
}
```

Comment: Just a head up, using simply an increment counter could come back to bite you, and cause unexpected results. And a random key is not great either. If you have some sort of unique ID on the jobResource, it's best to use that as a key on the UL. That way, React will operate on the correct UL when you manipulate the list, instead of redrawing the whole thing, and e.g. removing the bottom one when you remove a job resource. As for the `li` elements, the keys could just be the strings `"name"` and `"type"`.

Comment: @dannyjolie: Thanks for the heads up regarding the ul elements, I will change that. However, for the li elements, what if two resources have the same name (the type is too common to use as a key anyway)? That will be a problem, won't it?

Comment: They only have to be unique relative to each other. That is, the two `li` elements in the same parent `ul`. Elements in different parents may very well have the same key, because the complete id is a long string that is inherited from the parents, with key appended at the end.

Comment: You're welcome! I find `key={jobResource.resource.name}` might be a bit overkill though. Besides, in the odd case of resource.name and resource.resourceType.name being identical, it will fail again. As long as you know there's always going to be two `li` elements, you can just have simple keys, the strings i mentioned will be more that enough, and you don't have to validate any random data.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this

```
if (this.state.jobResources) {
  jobResources = _.map(this.state.jobResources, function(jobResource, i) {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li key={i.toString()}>{jobResource.resource.name}</li>
        <li key={`key${i}`}>
          {
            translations.resourceType[
              jobResource.resource.resourceType.name
            ]
          }
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  });
}
```